# How do I compute a prediction interval from generalized estimating equation output?

Tags: generalized-estimating-equations, prediction-interval

Suppose I have repeated observations on individuals, which I've analyzed using a generalized estimating equation (GEE). What is the procedure for computing the prediction interval for future observations given values of the predictors? I would appreciate either instructions or references. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of GEE is this (e.g. Gaussian, Binomial, Poisson, etc..)? Do you have access (or can you calculate) to the covariance matrix of the parameter estimates?

Comment: I asked the question for poisson gee.